# Unable to change form text input value using react context api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I'm using the react context API to help with state management and I'm able to set form input values on page load, but I cannot change the values. When I type anything to an input the text will not change. I'm not quite sure how to bind input values to the state managed through the context api. Thanks

```
import React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";

const defaultComponentState = {
    data: {
        input_1: 123,
    }
}

const componentStateFuncs = {
    funcs: {
        updateInput1: (val) => {},
    }
}
const MyComponentDataContext = React.createContext({...defaultComponentState,...componentStateFuncs})


const myComponentDataReducer = (state, action) => {
    if (action.type === "UPDATE_INPUT_1") {
        state.data.input_1 = action.val
    }
    return state
}


const MyComponentDataProvider = (props) => {
    let [componentState, dispatchComponentAction] = React.useReducer(myComponentDataReducer, defaultComponentState)

    const updateInput1Value = (val) => {
        dispatchComponentAction({type: "UPDATE_INPUT_1", val: val})
    }
    const componentContext = {
        funcs: {
            updateInput1: updateInput1Value,
        },
        data: {
            input_1: componentState.data.input_1,
        }
    }
    console.log(`State in MyComponentDataProvider: ${JSON.stringify(componentState)}`)
    return (
        <MyComponentDataContext.Provider value={componentContext}>
            {props.children}
        </MyComponentDataContext.Provider>
    )
}


const MyComponent = (props) => {
    const myComponentCtx = React.useContext(MyComponentDataContext);

    const input1Handler = (event) => {
        myComponentCtx.funcs.updateInput1(event.target.value);
    }

    const submitForm = (event) => {
        props.onSubmitSearch(myComponentCtx.data)
    }

    return (
        <div id="my_component">
            <form onSubmit={submitForm}>
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="input_1">Input 1</label><br/>
                    <input name="input_1" type="number" onChange={input1Handler} value={myComponentCtx.data.input_1}></input>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button id="myComponentSubmit" className="btn btn-outline-light" type="submit">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}


const App = () => {
    const handleSubmitForm = async (params) => {
        console.log(`State in handleSubmitForm: ${JSON.stringify(params)}`)
    };

    return (
        <div id="app-container">
            <MyComponentDataProvider>
                <div id="mycomponent-container">
                    <MyComponent 
                        onSubmitSearch={handleSubmitForm}>
                    </MyComponent>
                </div>
            </MyComponentDataProvider>
        </div>
    );
}

const container = document.getElementById('app');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(container);
root.render(<App  />);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1-Updating State in Reducer:

```
const myComponentDataReducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === "UPDATE_INPUT_1") {
    return {
      ...state,
      data: {
        ...state.data,
        input_1: action.val,
      },
    };
  }
  return state;
};
```

> 2-Debugging Component State:

```
const input1Handler = (event) => {
  myComponentCtx.funcs.updateInput1(event.target.value);
  console.log(`Updated Input 1 Value: ${event.target.value}`);
};
```